# Gravitational wave energy fluxes and bracket averaging notation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

Typically the rate of energy loss due to gravitational waves is given in the form (e.g. MTW or [Eq 33 of these notes](http://www.mit.edu/~iancross/8901_2019A/lec005.pdf)),

$$ \dot{E} = - \frac{1}{5} \langle \dddot{I}_{jk} \dddot{I}_{jk} \rangle$$

where an overdot represents a time derivative and $I_{jk}$ is the mass quadrupole tensor.

I am a bit confused by exactly what the $\langle \rangle$ brackets mean however? They are usually described as denoting an average over some time period or over several wavelengths, but why is such an averaging needed? If I have some time series of $\dddot{I}_{jk}$ can I not just at every timestep $t$ calculate $\dot{E} (t)$? Where does an averaging come in?

Thanks